# WSO2SP authentication with WSO2AM-KM

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'd like to authenticate the WSO2SP dashboard with users from the WSO2AM as IdP if possible (https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP420/User+Management+via+the+IdP+Client+Interface).

I made the following configuration (port 9446 is for the Key Manager)

```
auth.configs:
 type: external
 properties:
  kmDcrUrl: https://server:9446/identity/connect/register
  kmTokenUrl: https://server:9446/oauth2
  kmUsername: admin
  kmPassword: admin
  idpBaseUrl: https://server:9446/scim2
  idpUsername: admin
  idpPassword: admin
  portalAppContext: portal
  statusDashboardAppContext: monitoring
  businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
  databaseName: WSO2_OAUTH_APP_DB
  cacheTimeout: 900
  baseUrl: https://server:9643
  grantType: password
```

Apparently the URL `https://server:9446/identity/connect/register`return 403 status.

Questions:

- Do I need to use a full Identity Server to authenticate the SP with WSO2AM users?
- If I can use a KM DCR service from WSO2AM, is which URL is it?

Answer (score 0):

Even if we use WSO2AM DCR service WSO2AM 2.x does not have SCIM2 support and we can't use the External IdP without SCIM2